# How to save MDX query and use it for next time?

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, olap, cube

I can write MDX queries in `SSAS` project but, I don't know how to save that and use MDX'queries for next time.

for example I Wrote MDX queries

```
WITH 
 MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS 
  Max
  (
   nonempty(
    [Date Skey].[Date Key].MEMBERS
    ,[Measures].[Qty - Fact Out Puts Warehouse]
  )
 ,[Date Skey].[Date Key]
) 
SELECT 
 {
  [Measures].[Max key]
 } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cas Dw];
```

how Can I Use From Member [Max key] In PowerPivot Excel

Comment: Can you provide screenshot as this is not very clear question :/
Are you using cube browser ?

Comment: Yes, I Use Cube. I Wrote MDX Query And How to Save as a member And I Use in Excel (Pivot Table)

Answer (score 2):

You could add this query in SSS project->Cube->Calculation like below
[image]
Then  deploy it  and you could use it next time.